# Creating unique nodes from existing nodes' properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Essentially, I have a set of transactions with senders and receivers:

```
Transaction 1 - Sender Joe - Receiver Bob
Transaction 2 - Sender Bob - Receiver Sam
Transaction 3 - Sender Bob - Receiver Nick
```

My goal is to take each unique sender and receiver and create a unique Person Node, with additional properties, like `last_online` and `email`, and eventually, the relationship chain `(Person) -> sends -> (Transaction) -> to -> (Person)`. I have a small subset of these users already defined, and I want to combine the unknown and known users into the same set.

I've tried using `merge` and `create_unique`, and I end up creating duplicate nodes for every single Person-Transaction relationship, which I now understand why ([As explained here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/)). However, I still can't figure out how to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

Edit: Here are the queries that I am running:

```
MATCH (t:Transaction) MERGE (p:Person{name:t.sender}) - [:sends] -> (t)
MATCH (t:Transaction) MERGE (t) - [:to] -> (p:Person{name:t.sender})
```

Each of these queries creates `n` wallets for each of the `n` transactions.

Comment: did you try unique constraints on the sender's properties?

Comment: @ShaikRizwana yup. All the constraint does is block the merge clause from creating duplicates (by throwing an error) but beyond that, it's not actually creating the unique nodes and linking them across the query. The problem is that due to the nature of the merge function, it's perceiving every new "person where person.name = transaction.sender" as a unique node, so it tries to create a new node (and fails due to the constraint).

Comment: Can you share with us your `MERGE` query ? I think you have done a mistake in it

Comment: @logisima Updated the post with the queries.

Comment: @thevises did you try MERGE with ON MATCH SET and ON CREATE SET? that's how you avoid the duplicates and error too. If you apply unique constraint on name then no duplicate relations or nodes for. Can you also share the UI of the schema or the query's display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must carefully specify the pattern used with `MERGE`. If `MERGE` does not find an exact match on the *entire* pattern, it will create that *entire* pattern (even the parts of the pattern that already exist).

Something like the following should work (assuming that `t` also contains a transaction `id` and extra transaction data `foo`):

```
MERGE (s:Person {name: t.sender})
MERGE (r:Person {name: t.receiver})
MERGE (trans:Transaction {id: t.id})
SET trans.foo = t.foo
MERGE (s)-[:sends]->(trans)
MERGE (trans)-[:to]->(r);
```

To speed up processing, you should first [create indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-single-property-index) on `:Person(name)` and `:Transaction(id)`.

Comment: This worked, but I'm still a little bit confused as to why it worked. What about this query made it an improvement over my original query? Thanks.

Comment: Your query has a lot of issues, so I won't go into all of them. But as for `MERGE` -- you basically want to write each `MERGE` clause so that it can only create at most one node or relationship at a time.